# Remove an array item nested inside of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, array-splice

I'm trying to remove a specific item from an objects array based on the title attribute in the array. I keep running into a problem where I can view the array item, but I'm not able to splice the item out of the array based on the parameters entered in my remove function. I'm just getting the error message back from my `else` statement in the function.

I've tried using `find, forEach, findIndex` and match that case in order to test out removing the result based on the index, or the text value of the `key 'text'`. I commented out all of the functions I tried prior to searching for the answer in the forum recommendations. All of my recipe functions are working, along with my `createIngredient` function, which adds an object to the recipe array. But the `removeIngredient` function I've been trying to get to work, isn't because of the problems mentioned above.

```
let recipes = []

// Read existing recipes from localStorage
const loadRecipes = () => {
    const recipesJSON = localStorage.getItem('recipes')

    try {
        return recipesJSON ? JSON.parse(recipesJSON) : []
    } catch (e) {
        return []
    } 
}

// Expose recipes from module
const getRecipes = () => recipes

const createRecipe = () => {
    const id = uuidv4()
    const timestamp = moment().valueOf()

    recipes.push({
        id: id,
        title: '',
        body: '',
        createdAt: timestamp,
        updatedAt: timestamp,
        ingredient: []
    })
    saveRecipes()

    return id
}

// Save the recipes to localStorage
const saveRecipes = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('recipes', JSON.stringify(recipes))
}

// Remove a recipe from the list
const removeRecipe = (id) => {
    const recipeIndex = recipes.findIndex((recipe) => recipe.id === id)

    if (recipeIndex > -1) {
        recipes.splice(recipeIndex, 1)
        saveRecipes()
    }
}

// Remove all recipes from the recipe array
const cleanSlate = () => {
    recipes = []
    saveRecipes()
}

const updateRecipe = (id, updates) => {
    const recipe = recipes.find((recipe) => recipe.id === id)

    if (!recipe) {
        return
    }

    if (typeof updates.title === 'string') {
        recipe.title = updates.title
        recipe.updatedAt = moment().valueOf()
    }

    if (typeof updates.body === 'string') {
        recipe.body = updates.body
        recipe.updateAt = moment().valueOf()
    }

    saveRecipes()
    return recipe
}

const createIngredient = (id, text) => {
    const recipe = recipes.find((recipe) => recipe.id === id)

    const newItem = {
        text,
        have: false
    }
    recipe.ingredient.push(newItem)
    saveRecipes()
}

const removeIngredient = (id) => {
    const ingredient = recipes.find((recipe) => recipe.id === id)
    console.log(ingredient)
    const allIngredients = ingredient.todo.forEach((ingredient) => console.log(ingredient.text))

    // const recipeIndex = recipes.find((recipe) => recipe.id === id)

    // for (let text of recipeIndex) {
    //     console.log(recipdeIndex[text])
    // }

// Attempt 3
    // if (indexOfIngredient === 0) {
    //     ingredientIndex.splice(index, 1)
    //     saveRecipes()
    // } else {
    //     console.log('error')
    // }
    // Attempt 2
    // const recipe = recipes.find((recipe) => recipe.id === id)
    // const ingredients = recipe.todo 
    // // let newItem = ingredients.forEach((item) => item)

    // if (ingredients.text === 'breadcrumbs') {
    //     ingredients.splice(ingredients, 1)
    //     saveRecipes()
    // }
    // Attempt 1
    // const ingredientName = ingredients.forEach((ingredient, index, array) => console.log(ingredient, index, array))
    // console.log(ingredientName)

    // const recipeIndex = recipes.findIndex((recipe) => recipe.id === id)

    // if (recipeIndex > -1) {
    //     recipes.splice(recipeIndex, 1)
    //     saveRecipes()
    // }
}

recipes = loadRecipes()
```

OUTPUT

```
{id: "ef88e013-9510-4b0e-927f-b9a8fc623450", title: "Spaghetti", body: "", createdAt: 1546878594784, updatedAt: 1546878608896, …}
recipes.js:94 breadcrumbs
recipes.js:94 noodles
recipes.js:94 marinara
recipes.js:94 meat
recipes.js:94 ground beef
recipes.js:94 milk
```

So I'm able to view the output I printed above and see each item in the `ingredients` array, but trying to splice the item based on the `index` number or `key` is not working for me with the functions I have already tried and the info I have found on Stackoverflow about objects, arrays and the splice method so far.

Comment: You should consider editing the question so it clearly shows the data you are starting with and what you hope to see at the end. If all the event handlers aren't part of the problem, they probably don't need to be in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly (after reading the commented out attempts in your code), you are trying to remove the "breadcrumbs" ingredient from the recipe that corresponds to the `id` passed to the `removeIngredient()` function.

In that case, perhaps you could take a slightly different approach to removing the ingredient from the recipes `todo` array, via the [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method?

You could use `filter()` in the following way to "filter out" (ie remove) the "breadcrumbs" ingredient from the `todo` array via the following filter logic:

```
// Keep any ingredients that do not match ingredient (ie if ingredient
// equals "breadcrumbs")
todo.filter(todoIngredient => todoIngredient !== ingredient)
```

You might consider revising your `removeIngredient()` function by;

- adding an additional `ingredient` parameter to the function arguments. This allows you to specify the ingredient to be removed from the recipe corresponding to `recipeId`
- and, introducing the `filter()` idea as described:

---

```
const removeIngredient = (recipeId, ingredient) => {

    const recipe = recipes.find(recipe => recipe.id === recipeId)

    if(recipe) {

        // Filter recipe.todo by ingredients that do not match  
        // ingredient argument, and reassign the filtered array 
        // back to the recipie object we're working with
        recipe.todo = recipe.todo.filter(todoIngredient => 
                                         (todoIngredient !== ingredient));
    }

}
```

Now, when you introduce the "remove" button for each ingredient, you would call the `removeIngredient()` as follows:

```
var recipeId = /* got id from somewhere */
var ingredientText = /* got ingredient from somewhere */

removeIngredient( recipeId, ingredientText );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Denny, thanks! I feel like maybe I worded the result I'm expecting incorrectly. I tried the filter method, and it looks like it's doing what it's supposed to and returning a new array with only breadcrumbs. Ultimately, what I want is to have each object, e.g. breadcrumbs, noodles, marinara to have a 'remove' button next to each one, and if the user clicks on it, the function will splice the item from the array. That's what I'm ultimately trying to achieve with the `removeIngredient` function. I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Ang you're welcome - would you like me to update the answer to allow for different ingredients to be removed via `removeIngredient()` ?

Comment: Yes, Denny! Thanks.

Comment: No problems @Ang! Have just updated answer - does this help?

Comment: Yes, sir! I appreciate your help! I marked this as solved.

Comment: @Ang great! Glad I could help :-)